# windows 8 laptop wakes from sleep while lid closed

Tags: windows-8

I am having issues with my windows 8.1 laptop waking from sleep while the lid is closed. I keep it in a sleeve which keeps the lid closed tight. It seemed as though the slightest bump can cause it to wake, but not always. (a mystery)

Other site seem to say it is impossible to disable the lid open wake feature. They say if you open the lid, why shouldn't turn on. In my case is kills my battery and i am afraid it will start a fire in a confined space.

Here are some of the things I tried:

- disable sleep on lid close. This did not fix the problem.
- ran cmd.exe (run as administrator) to gain access to devices that wake from sleep `powercfg.exe /DEVICEquery wake_armed`. This gave me 4 devices that were configured to wake from sleep. one was the mouse which i disabled with `powercfg.exe /DEVICEDISABLEWAKE "HID-compliant mouse"`. I did this for all four devices. (I am still waiting to see if this solved the problem. I bounced the device on the table and it did not wake up this time).

What am I missing here.

I use a wireless mouse and keyboard. they both have off switches. I disable the wake on the premise that I might not always turn them off. They are in my bag with my laptop. I considered any movement might wake the laptop. I moved the mouse and struct keys on the keyboard and it did not wake the laptop.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: What brand is the laptop?  I have seen a lot of problems with Toshiba laptops having problems with automatically turning themselves on or failing to properly turn themselves off.  Either way, the result is a dead battery.  I recommend staying away from that brand.

Comment: toshiba qosmio x70-a

Comment: Congrats on resolving the problem yourself! I have rolled back your edit. Super User is not a forum and it works in quite a different way. If you have found a solution, then post it as an answer to your question. Don't edit the title and don't add *"solved"*. Instead, post a solution and mark it as a correct answer (you'll have to wait 48 hours IIRC).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You mentioned wireless devices in your bag. The laptop with the lid down can wake from sleep. After the time expires from no activity, the laptop goes to sleep. The length is determined by the power settings in the power control panel. This explains the battery drain, since the fan runs full speed to cool the CPU.

You could run **cmd.exe** as administrator to get around permission errors. But, this does not always work. A better solution is running psexec which makes you localservice. This does not have permission issues removing devices that wake from sleep.

Here is the link https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896649.aspx or http://download.sysinternals.com/files/PSTools.zip to psexec, part of the Microsoft sysinternals.

Use

```
psexec -i -d -s cmd.exe
```

to gain access to localservice. From there run:

```
powercfg.exe /DEVICEQUERY wake_armed
```

It shows a list of devices that can wake the laptop from sleep. I did this on all my laptops. Each one had different devices that could wake it from sleep. Now, to be safe, I removed all of them so that nothing could wake it up. Remove as many as you like.

Run this command to remove a device:

```
powercfg.exe /DEVICEDISABLEWAKE "your device string goes here"
```

Like

```
powercfg.exe /DEVICEDISABLEWAKE "HID-compliant mouse (001)"
```

I ran this for each one and verified by running

```
powercfg.exe /DEVICEQUERY wake_armed
```

again. This time I received **None**.

I have not had any of my laptops wake up since.

Comment: Thanks! turned me nuts and this solved it. Everytime I closed the lid I went to sleep and woke up instantly again without me toughing or moving anything.